# How to take count of sub-categories and update parent row count in mysql using single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I am stroring categories and sub categories in same table. How can I take count of all subcategories and update my parent category row of data.

```
categoryId   sub cat id    category_count        subcategory_count
        1           3               0                      3              
        1           4               0                      1
        1           5               0                      7
        1           0               5                      0
```

I need to update category count with sum of sub category count.

`for eg;- 5 is my category count. I want my category count like this`
`5+ (3+7+1) so my category count should be 16`

How can I write a single query for that.

please help me
Thanks

Comment: If you update `category_count`, the next time the query is ran, it will add them all up again, so instead of `16` it would become `27` the next time. Is this intended?

Comment: @learner Is either the `category_count` or `subcategory_count` recursive? I.e. how do you handle sub-sub-categories, sub-sub-sub-categories etc...

Answer (score -2):

Hope this one help::

```
Select (sum(subcatecory_count)+category_count), category_count from table group by category_count;
```

Comment: Hi Sashi kant with out grouping with category_count does it possible to do?

Comment: u have to get the count category wise so u need to group